# dependencias incumplidas: php7.2-zip : Depende: libzip4 (>= 1.0)

Tags: php, ubuntu, servidor

Estoy tratando de instalar php7.2-zip en ubuntu server 18.04 pero al momento de tratar de instalarlo me da este error "dependencias incumplidas:
 php7.2-zip : Depende: libzip4 (>= 1.0)" y trato de instalar libzip4 pero me manda esto "El paquete libzip4 no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente".
 Ya no se que hacer espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo! 
Si estas usando un sitema 64-bits proba con esto

```
sudo apt-get purge libzip4
```

Luego

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
```

Si tenes un sitema 32-bits

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip:i386
```

Fuente: https://askubuntu.com/questions/933074/attempting-to-install-php-zip-getting-libzip4-dependancy-1-0-error-even-th